# how do I forget the last user using facebook js sdk

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

When I use FB.logout() the user gets logged out fine, but then the next time I do FB.login() it logs in the last user without the option to enter in new credentials. I can't find any information on how to forget the previously signed on user. Is there a parameter I can pass into logout or login that would forget the previous user?

Comment: i believe it´s not possible, because the app should not be able to logout completely from facebook. what´s the use case anyway?

Comment: @luschn I want the login screen to pop up every time that a user clicks login, that way they have to opportunity to switch accounts if theyd like. As of right now the login screen doesn't even pop up, the previous user just automatically gets logged in.

Comment: ok, that is a different thing, of course that´s possible by just deleting the permissions...

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the behavior I wanted could be achieved by deleting the users permissions with the following snippet before logging the user out.

```
FB.api(`/${fbUserId}/permissions`,
       'delete',
       {access_token: fbUserAccessToken})
```